# How to run Laravel/Homestead on already setup VirtualBox?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to install laravel/homestead on a VirtualBox using vagrant/Oracle VM VirtualBox.

I realize that I can add Homestead box via the command line like so

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

The problem with that, it creates a Dynamic Size hard drive which makes the VM performance bad and the respond is very slow.

To solve for that, I manually created a VM box with a Fixed size HD using the VM VirtualBox Manager GUI.

Now, I need to run homestead on the box that I manually created.

How do I run Homestead on the the box that I created "devBox"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` command you are downloading a whole new box to the vagrant box list so you can start using that box but it will be (as I said) a new box, you can't run a box inside another box, you need to run each one separately.

Each box is a brand new virtual machine so you would have 2 virtual machines on your virtualbox, one for laravel homestead and one for devBox

Comment: I see. So what do I do to make the laravel/homestead box have fixed HD size?

Comment: Laravel homestead comes with a dynamical  40GB HD size, this means that the actual size of your HD will be only the used by the VM with a top of 40GB, so you shouldn't have any problems with that, are you getting an error when you try to run the machine normally?

Comment: It runs super slow with dynamic size

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: windows 7 on the machine and Ubuntu 64 but on the VM

Comment: Have you enabled the hardware virtualization (VT-x) on the BIOS?

Comment: if you look at this topic you it states to convert from dynamic to fixed to help performance https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/for-those-who-find-homesteadvagrantvirtualbox-slow-on-windows  then the following URL talks about to convert the HD type but it is not working for me http://maxrohde.com/2014/06/21/convert-dynamically-sized-virtualbox-vdi-hard-drive-to-fixed-size/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85247/discussion-between-dimitri-acosta-and-mike-a).